# MySql INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with time condition

Tags: php, mysql, insert, on-duplicate-key

I have a table which logs IP addresses (index) and time stamp after form submission which cannot be resubmitted within, say, a minute. I've got the logic working for INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE which inserts a row if there's no IP in the table or updates the row if the IP is already there and it will keep updating it. What I need is it should:

1. Insert row if no IP
2. Update row if IP but now() < timestamp
3. Insert new row if now() > timestamp

This is what I've got so far:

```
$q = 'INSERT INTO btTable (ip, timestamp) 
        VALUES(INET_ATON (?),?) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE timestamp = ?';

$v = [$this->host_ip, date('YmdHi'), date('YmdHi')];
$db->executeQuery($q, $v);
```

Thank you.

Comment: ON DUPLICATE isn't going to help you anymore.

Comment: You might have to handle this using a trigger.